# Samsung J5 | Overheating after restart | TouchWiz has stopped working

Tags: samsung, samsung-touchwiz

After restarting my Samsung J5 (8gb) , it started overheating and then all of a sudden it said "TouchWiz has stopped working" (I was unable to interact with the touchscreen thereafter). After pulling out the battery and restarting the phone , the exact same thing happened. I am now charging my phone (While its switched off), and it is overheating .

What should i do to rectify this problem ? Please give some advice.

Comment: TouchWiz is the user interface. When it crashes, you can't interact with the touchscreen. Why is it happening I really don't know. But starting with a factory reset is always a good approach to see if it fixes anything.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the eMMC as it overheats or any other chip on the motherboard. Hardware issue.

Comment: @SarpSTA , thanks for the feedback guys. My phone isn't starting at all now

Comment: @esQmo thanks for your feedback ! Do you think it's advisable to get another Samsung J5  or another smartphone  (perhaps a Huwai p8 ) ?

Comment: I think so, but I would try flashing it first.

Comment: @MichaelAndréSlimz Cellphone recommendations are off-topic. We can only use the site for Android related user problems. I'd suggest doing a factory reset first. Problem might be related to cache or data and factory reset might fix that. Try it first.